# Unable to set initial value when databinding combobox to Dictionary<char,string>

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dictionary, combobox

I have a simple Dictionary defined as ResultOptions = new `Dictionary<char, string>` and my viewmodel has a public property ResultCode of type char. My XAML is as follow:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ResultOptions}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                            SelectedValuePath="Key"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding ResultCode}" />
```

Everything is working great except the ComboBox is never initialized based on the value of SelectedValue. I'm sure the binding is correct since i'm able to see that the ResultCode in the viewmodel is set properly.

The strange thing is...if i change my model to have ResultCode to be of type 'string' and my dictionary is `Dictionary<string,string>`, then the combobox is initialized properly based on the SelectedValue.

What's am i missing? why is binding to `Dictionary<string, string>` works, but binding to  `Dictionary<char, string>` doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

One difference between the two cases is that `char` is a value type, while `string` is a reference type. Most likely internally WPF is using objects for bindings, and every time the `char` is received, it is boxed into a new object, so a reference equality check fails.

I'd say just use a `string` as your key, since there isn't any way to get around how boxing works.

Comment: Thanks! We did decide to use string as the key for now.

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question so that the question no longer shows up as not having an accepted answer.